# Flutter Apk Size greater than 100 mb

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to release the flutter app into playstore. but when I made it, it's more than 100 mb. I cleaned and re build the apk but still it's greater than 100mb. my assets directory contains a simple image file only 1kb file. My app is a image to text converter which uses google ml kit. I don't know how to reduce it.

Comment: Which method you are using for build `APK` ?

Comment: flutter build appbundle

Comment: Hey, did you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: Yeah ...It's 42 mb now

Answer (score 1):

Build your app with below command

```
flutter build appbundle --release
```

upload the appbundle file on playstore

you can find the build version of your app in `build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab`

check this location for actual size, this can be a case where you are checking size of debug build of your app which is generally bigger.

also make sure you are not using any big asset files in your app

your app size should be less than 25Mb as per the details you shared.

your build file will be of this size, on user end it will be reflected in between a range of 10-14 mb app size

Comment: When I tried with that command. I got this Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It's being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. So now I need to migrate.

Comment: I will recreate the project and try again.

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment.